# Custom sort in iOS, want to show default(All Group) title on top from Coredata

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I am using core data with `NSFetchedResultController`. In this case, I have an `n` number of user groups and a user can select a particular group or select `all group`. So manually I added `All group` title, `static ID` and relevant content to the database.

```
NSFetchRequest <IRSUserAssetGroup *> *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName: [IRSUserAssetGroup entityName]];

NSSortDescriptor *nameSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: NSStringFromSelector(@selector(assetGroupName))
                                                                     ascending: YES
                                                                      selector: @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors: @[nameSortDescriptor]];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize: 4];

NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [[IRSCoreDataManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext];

NSFetchedResultsController <IRSUserAssetGroup *> *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest: fetchRequest
                                                                                                                 managedObjectContext: mainContext
                                                                                                                   sectionNameKeyPath: nil
                                                                                                                            cacheName: nil];

NSError *fetchError = nil;

if (![fetchedResultsController performFetch: &fetchError])
    FCALog(@"fetch error: %@", fetchError);

[self setUserAssetGroupFetchedResultsController: fetchedResultsController];
```

This is my `FRC` code. I am using sort by name. Some group name has start with the number. Because of this `All group` not place in first place.

Is that possible `All group` place always top on sort?

Extra: I am using table view with search option

Example: `@[@1, @5, @"text", @"aaaaaaa", @"All group"]`. Here `All group` show always on top of the list. How can I sort like that.

Output: `@[@"All group", @1, @5,  @"aaaaaaa", @"text"]`

Comment: Don't solve this in the data model, but manually add the static cell in the TableViewDataSource. So the object at index 0 is you `All groups` cell, just remember to subtract 1 from the index when grabbing the item from the `FetchedresultsController`.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I am working kind of sort only. What do you think about the @jonRose answer? Which one is good, like efficient, speed, etc.,

Comment: As I mention before there is static `ID` for `All group`, Now I added and predicate `NSPredicate *allGroupPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K != %d", NSStringFromSelector(@selector(assetGroupID)), allUserGroupID];` with this. On `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Put static cell setup for `All group`. Is that what you try to convey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You and I know that 'All group' is special because we read and understand the word, but core data has no way of knowing that the 'All group' is special; all it sees it that it starts with an "A".  You could add another property to your Entity `isAllGroup` and first sort by that, and then by `assetGroupName`.

Or you can have a property 'groupOrder' which is 0 for the "all Group" and 100 for every other groups. This allows you to have more room to have other special group ordering without creating a new property.

An even more general approach would be to add a property `assetGroupNameForSort` and sort by that instead of `assetGroupName` which is used for display only.  For most group the values are identical but for the "All Group" it is "__All Group" or something like that. This can also be used fix issue that can happen with names that are in difference languages that are sorted in ways you don't expect.

I would recommend the first approach, just add an 'isAllGroup' property.  It is the simplest and the data is readily understandable.

Also: minor issue - a fetchedResultsController does not respect FetchBatchSize so you can remove it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the minor issue. Can you explain why? Because `FetchBatchSize` also part of fetch result means `NSFetchRequest`.

Comment: I don't want to update (or versioning) database for this minor change. So I am going with added another `AND` predicate `NSPredicate *allGroupPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K != %d", NSStringFromSelector(@selector(assetGroupID)), allUserGroupID];` with this. On `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Put static cell setup for `All group`. And once again thanks for more option to sort.

Comment: if a fetchedResultsController respected batchSize because apple did not write it to respect batchSize.  I would guess that they did this because it would add a huge amount of complexity to the code.  For example if there was an insert it would also cause a delete (because it went over the batchSize).

Comment: I don't think you should be afraid of a version model.  I do them all the time even for very minor changes.

Comment: Again thanks for an explanation. Previously I didn't try version model. That's why. Okay, let me give a shot for version model. (Mind voice) In the feature, Apple may consider this kind of sorting methods. Small sorting thing but few manual works.